# How can I do a select to not show when it has PDF in other table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a select to not show when it has a PDF in another column from my other table

```
SELECT * from blogs
```

```
|blogs|
 |id|  |number|
  1     423423
  2     432422
  3     123233
  4     324233
```

```
SELECT b.id, p.id, p.file_name FROM posts p, blogs b
```

```
|posts|
 |id|  |blog_id| |file_name|
   1       1       C://blog1.pdf
   2       1       C://blog2.pdf
   3       2       C://blog3.pdf
```

Trying to do all that doesn't have PDF

```
|id|    |number|   
 3       123233
 4       324233
```

Comment: How do you determine if a blog `has pdf`?

Comment: SELECT b.id, p.id,p.file_name FROM posts p ,blogs b group by blog_id

Comment: Not sure how that answers my question. Let me try a different approach. Are you looking for all blogs that are NOT referenced in the `blog_id` column of the posts table?

Comment: YES all blogs that doesn't have pdf

Comment: Ok, that's clear. I added an answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`. Try this out:

```
SELECT b.* FROM blogs b
LEFT JOIN posts p ON b.id = p.blog_id
WHERE p.blog_id IS NULL
```

Output:

```
| ID | NUMBER |
|----|--------|
|  3 | 123233 |
|  4 | 324233 |
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c804/1).

Comment: you are so great!!! :) thanks for your help it really worked for me and also thanks for Fiddle it is so clear for me  you won 1 point =)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.id, b.number FROM posts p INNER JOIN blogs b ON b.id= p.blog_id WHERE p.file_name NOT LIKE '%.pdf'
```

Try this. This is how it works in t-SQL not sure if its the same in MySQL

Comment: Well i understood your code but seems something is missing i feel it  WHERE p.file_name NOT LIKE '%.pdf'

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a left outer join (so blogs with no posts will be included), and then exclude any blogs with (PDF) posts.  This is technically called an anti-semi-join.

It works as follows in standard SQL, which should work in either T-SQL (MS SQL Server) or MySQL to the best of my knowledge:

```
SELECT b.id, b.number
FROM blogs AS b
LEFT OUTER JOIN posts AS p
ON p.blog_id = b.id
WHERE p.blog_id IS NULL
```

That's assuming all of the rows in the posts table have the file name column populated with a PDF name.  If this isn't always the case, and you need to only exclude blogs which have a PDF post rather than some other type of file, you'll need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT b.id, b.number
FROM blogs AS b
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT blog_id FROM posts WHERE file_name LIKE '%pdf') AS p
ON p.blog_id = b.id
WHERE p.blog_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a `JOIN`.  Depending on your table structure, you need to join the blogs table to the posts table.  Something like this:

```
SELECT b.id, b.number
FROM blogs b
    JOIN posts p ON b.id = p.blog_id
```

This assumes your posts table has a blog_id field.  If not, join on the appropriate field from both tables.  See below article to learn more about joins.

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)